# Running Powershell using administrator and server farm account

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I am a newbie in Powershell and would like to know if running a powershell command as administrator or service account is possible or not.

I tried running a Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath command as administrator and using server farm account but I got this error: "Access denied.". I checked the properties of SharePoint 2010 Management Shell and set the advanced property to "Run as administrator". I tried running the command both as administrator or as server farm account.

Comment: First obvious step: is the user you connect with a farm administrator?

Comment: Yes. I'm actually using the account of farm administrator. I tried running it as "administrator", using my account, and as "server farm administrator account". I got access denied error.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly is feasible to run "as administrator", but that is just fully enabling the access rights and privileges of a local administrator account otherwise limited by UAC.

To run an executable as an arbitrary user (ie. other than the current logon) either use remote desktop connection to connect with different credentials to a machine, or use `runas` from the command line (use `runas /?` to see usage).